# Generate a random string using ArangoDB's AQL?

Tags: arangodb, aql

Using AQL (preferably in the ArangoDB WebUI), is it possible to generate a random string or letters and numbers similar to this: `4EKH5G3AN6HH`?

If not, what is another way to do it without doing it in application code?

Comment: Looks like you can implement your own functions using javascript and then register them in AQL https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Extending/Functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/functions/string/#random_token

```
RANDOM_TOKEN(8) // "zGl09z42"
```

then you can apply https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/functions/string/#upper

```
UPPER(RANDOM_TOKEN(8)) // "ZGL09Z42"
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from sevcik.tk
Just in case, you can generate documents full of random data like that:

```
FOR i IN 1..300000
  INSERT {
    code: CONCAT("t", i),
    name: RANDOM_TOKEN(32),
    article1: RANDOM_TOKEN(10),
    article2: RANDOM_TOKEN(20)
  } IN batchtest
```

And there is link to useful functions:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/functions/string/#random_token